# Unable to get a specific value on a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the Facebook Javascript SDK to get inbox messages and so far I was able to get them and the transform it to a JSON object

`function getMsgs() {
        FB.api(
      "/me/inbox",
      function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
          var result = JSON.stringify(response);
            document.getElementById("msgs").innerHTML="<pre>"+result+"</pre>";
      }
    }
    );
}`

And what I end up getting is something like this:

`{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":"15986833470221166",
         "to":{  
            "data":[  
               {  
                  "id":"7888047207869023",
                  "name":"My Name"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"101530783476778608",
                  "name":"Friend Name"
               }
            ]
         },
         "updated_time":"2015-02-08T03:09:02+0000",
         "unread":5,
         "unseen":0,
         "comments":{  
            "data":[  
               {  
                  "id":"159268645347021166_1421118060",
                  "from":{  
                     "id":"7888047207869023",
                     "name":"My Name"
                  },
                  "message":"blah blah blah",
                  "created_time":"2015-01-13T03:01:00+0000"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"159268645347021166_1421118060",
                  "from":{  
                     "id":"7888047207869023",
                     "name":"My Name"
                  },
                  "message":"blah blah blah",
                  "created_time":"2015-01-13T03:01:16+0000"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"159268645347021166_1421118060",
                  "from":{  
                     "id":"101530783476778608",
                     "name":"Friend Name"
                  },
                  "message":"blah blah blah",
                  "created_time":"2015-01-13T03:01:23+0000"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"159268645347021166_1421118060",
                  "from":{  
                     "id":"101530783476778608",
                     "name":"Friend Name"
                  },
                  "message":"blah blah blah",
                  "created_time":"2015-01-13T03:01:30+0000"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"159268645347021166_1421118060",
                  "from":{  
                     "id":"101530783476778608",
                     "name":"Friend Name"
                  },
                  "message":"blah blah blah",
                  "created_time":"2015-02-08T03:09:02+0000"
               }
            ],
            "paging":{  
               "previous":"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/15986453474543021166/comments?access_token=TOKEN&limit=25&since=1423364314942&__paging_token=TOKEN&__previous=1",
               "next":"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/15986453474543021166/comments?access_token=TOKEN&limit=25&until=142111148324060&__paging_token=TOEKN"
            }
         }
      }`

I want to access the 'message' value. I want to create an array that stores every single message value in this JSON structure.

Comment: You can loop on `data[0].comments.data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to get the messages, you can do with

```
  if (response && !response.error) {
      var m=null
          , result=JSON.stringify(response)
          , re=/"message":"([^"]+)"/g
          , messages=[];
      while( m=re.exec(result) ) {
          messages.push(m[1]);
      }
      // messages array should now hold all the values by key "message"
      //console.log(messages);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `json`  you provided, you can do something like this:

```
// loop through the comments array
for ( var i = 0 ; i < json.data[0].comments.data.length; i++ )
{
    var d = json.data[0].comments.data[i];
    // codes here. Message is d.message

}
```

[SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/99ex3w61/)

Comment: This makes sense and your example works but for some reason it doesn't work with my code. Maybe it's because the JSON object is much bigger than the little snippet I posted here.