# Find e-mails on string

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I asked this question a few days ago:

[Unable to get a specific value on a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445991/unable-to-get-a-specific-value-on-a-json-object/28446378#28446378)

The first answer was just perfect. Now I need to modify that regular expression in order to find e-mails. The problem is I don't know anything about regular expressions and I've been looking around but don't seem to be able to pull it off.
This is the code:

```
var m=null
      , result=JSON.stringify(response)
      , re=/"message":"([^"]+)"/g
      , messages=[];
  while( m=re.exec(result) ) {
      messages.push(m[1]);
```

Everything is explained on my other question, but basically what this code does is get `message":"THIS TEXT"`
Now I want to find out whether that text contains an e-mail or not.

I've been checking out many javascript regexp examples and find it rather confusing so if you could give me a little explanation (or something to read) about why it's done the way it's done I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regexp you are looking for is long and ugly. The email address definition in RFC standard is too sophisticated and permissive. See "Valid email addresses" section on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address). But, you can check whether string looks like email with this simple regexp:

```
/^.+@.+\..+$/
```

The explanation of how this works can be found at [Regexper](http://regexper.com/#%2F%5E.%2B%40.%2B%5C..%2B%24%2F)

Comment: What I'm struggling with is adding this regular expression to the one that I already have /"message":"([^"]+)"/g

Comment: I don't have your input data to test, but try next:
`/"message":"([^@"]+@[^@"]+\.[^@"]+)"/g`

Comment: That line works perfect. What if I want to find a certain word in the message? (again, taking my regular expression as a starting point). Ex.: find "works" in "This regular expression works perfectly". Don't mean to be lazy, really took my time with this but just can't get it to work

Comment: You need only test if message contains some word?

Comment: Yep, basically. I want to check if message contains a certain word

Comment: <code>
var certainWord = "works"; 
var re = new RegExp(certainWord); // create new RegExp object from string in variable, I think it helps you
re.test("This regular expression works perfectly"); // true
re.test("This regular expression suck less"); // false
</code>

Answer (score 1):

There are some very, very long regexes that you can use to validate emails based on RFC standards. [Here is a regex that verifies regexes based on RFC882](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html), which is anything from short and easy-to-understand.

If you wanted to validate anything that *looked* like an email, you could use this:

```
^.+@.+\..+$
```

But, this regex will also allow spaces, and multiple @ symbols. So, you could use this:

```
^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+$
```

But this will allow special characters in the name and TLD, so, here's a short regex that will match almost all English emails (as well as those that aren't english):

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\~\!\$\&\'\(\)\*\+\,;\:\=]+)\@(.+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,36})$
```

This regex will match the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `-`, `_`, `~`, `!`, `$`, `&`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `*`, `+`, `,`, `;`, `:`, and `=` one or more times before the `@` symbol, will match any characters after the `@` symbol (almost all characters are now allowed with the new international domains), and allows `a-z` or `A-Z` 2 or more times as the TLD.

There are some international domains that do not have english characters in them, so it may be best to replace `[a-zA-Z]{2,36}` with `.{2,36}`, if you're expecting and international audience.

[Here's a live preview of Regex #1](https://regex101.com/r/tC2pT7/1) on regex101.com.

[Here's a live preview of Regex #2](https://regex101.com/r/tC2pT7/2) on regex101.com.

[Here's a live preview of Regex #3](https://regex101.com/r/tC2pT7/3) on regex101.com.